# how to playback same mp3/audio file in a loop with reduced playback speed

Tags: audio, audio-controls, loopback

I have downloaded a bunch of audio files. Sometimes I need to play an individual file in a loop several times, with a slower speed, e.g. 0.8. At the moment I use Google Files, I open Downloads folder, I double click on a file to play and then I can change speed to 0.8 or 0.5 from the three dot menu. However if I fail to restart file fast, the player jumps to the next audio file.

I imagine that creating a separate subfolder for each file may help, but wonder are there any better solutions? I tried a couple of random audio players but did not find features I want.